# Best place in .git folder for an add-on specific directory?

Tags: git

I am writing a Git add-on that requires a directory where special files can be placed that affect the local behavior of the add-on that I am writing. The contents of this directory can differ not only from one project to another, but even from one clone of the project to another - therefore it is important that the contents of this directory do *not* get exchanged, even in the event of pulling, pushing, or cloning of the repository.

Though the purpose of these files does involve configuration - it can not go into ".git/config" because these can *not* be mere variable-values, but *must* be full-fledged files.

Currently, I have this in a special directory *outside* of the .git directory - and exchange of the data is prevented by the fact that the add-on requires that this directory be registered in ".gitignore". However - I am wondering if there is a better way to do this -- as in, within the .git directory.

My question is this --- are there any recommended "best, safe practices" for me to do this that will minimize the chances of my add-on interfering with anything else or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't care if you add files to the .git directory.  Just don't stomp on the files that it uses such as HEAD, FETCH_HEAD etc.  For example you can copy the .git/config file to .git/config.save to have a backup while editing the config file.  When git does pushes/pulls/clones etc. It only references the files that it needs.